# MySQL reading date from CSV

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

Right now I have a database in the format with columns:

```
id - purchase_date - integer fields.....
```

And an import of a CSV using the script

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/work/natgas2.csv' INTO TABLE pricemodel.natural_gas 
   FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ',' 
        ENCLOSED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

And everything's being imported correctly except for the dates which are in the format right now of:

```
1/3/2011
```

So the question is what format do they have to be in for them to be read correctly into my database?

Comment: MySQL expects `YYYY-MM-DD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format should be: `YYYY-MM-DD`, e.g. `2011-01-03`.

Here's a way to do it (I'm assuming you're using phpMyAdmin):

1. Go to the table structure. Change the `date` column's type to `VARCHAR`.
2. Import everything into the database using the SQL you wrote.
3. Run a query like this: `UPDATE your_table SET date = STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y');`
4. Now go back into the table structure and change the column type back to `DATE`.

Comment: right now it's a date

Comment: Okay, same thing but without the time part, i.e. it should be in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD` (`2011-01-03`).

Comment: If you're using PHP, you can reformat these dates quickly with a function like `$date = strtotime('1/3/2011'); $stamp = date('Y-m-d');`.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with the SQL query that I wrote because I'm doing it manually through the workbench not in my program?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it would be possible through the SQL itself, but depending on your program, you might be able to find a way. In fact, if it's a CSV file, you could open it in a program like Notepad++ and use a regex find/replace. It'd be rather complicated to write, but it's certainly the right way to go about it, if you have thousands of rows.

Comment: Oh! I know! See my changed answer in a few minutes while I write it..

Comment: that's easier than what I ended up doing. I ended up just bringing it in as a string and converting it in my entity.